# Understanding the overhead from std::function and capturing synchronous lambdas

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, inline, std-function

Consider the following trivial example:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <QRandomGenerator>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <functional>

inline void reader(int * d, int c, std::function<void(int *)> foo) {
  while (c--) foo(d++);
}

template <class FOO>
inline void readerT(int * d, int c, FOO foo) {
  while (c--) foo(d++);
}

inline int summer(int * d, int c) {
  int s = 0;
  reader(d, c, [&s](int * dd){ s += *dd; });
  return s;
}

inline int summerT(int * d, int c) {
  int s = 0;
  readerT(d, c, [&s](int * dd){ s += *dd; });
  return s;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  int tcount = 100000000;

  QVector<int> vec; vec.resize(tcount);
  QRandomGenerator gen = QRandomGenerator::securelySeeded();  
  gen.generate(vec.begin(), vec.end());

  QElapsedTimer t;
  t.restart();
  qDebug() << summer(vec.data(), tcount) << t.elapsed(); // 110 ms
  t.restart();
  qDebug() << summerT(vec.data(), tcount) << t.elapsed(); // 15 ms

  t.restart();
  int sum = 0;
  for (const auto & i : vec) { sum += i; }
  qDebug() << sum << t.elapsed(); // 15 ms

  return a.exec();
}
```

The test makes it evident that the non-template solution is considerably slower, where the template solution appears to be as fast as the regular loop, or zero overhead.

Why is the compiler not able to reach the same level of optimization for the non-template version?

Notes: compiled with GCC11 O3

Comment: Have you looked at the generated assembly?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the optimization level is mentioned, I am not that much interested in what the compiler generates, but why it isn't able to inline it in this seeming "static" context which seems like it outta be more optimizable.

Comment: Compilers are not obligated to do such optimizations. And therefore the simple answer is: because the compiler wasn't coded to do that. Now are you really interested in the internals of the compiler? Because if you are interested in writing fast code, then the answer is: use templates. That's all.

Comment: Also, using `std::function` adds extra object construction, extra indirection and of course extra object destruction.

Comment: @freakish I am requesting a high optimization level, from a compiler for a language whose very motivation is high performance. I do not think it is an unreasonable expectation that it does its best. Also, quite dogmatic, and not at all informative your last bit of advice.

Comment: On an off-topic note, I can't help to think that there must be standard library algorithm functions to do what your code is doing. Which might, or might not, be more effective.

Comment: @dtech it does its best. Its just that you expect more from it than it gives you. Optimizing away std::function is impossible in general. Spending time for such trivial cases is generally a waste of effort, because in real world code such simple patterns just don't occur. In real code the compiler doesn't have enough information to deduce what std::function really is and inline it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it is the design of the code base I am working on, not my call. And besides, I doubt any std solution will get better than "zero overhead".

Comment: @dtech well, my advice is to not depend on compiler optimizations when you want to write performance critical code. That's the real cause of under performing software. Do you think that people that write databases or games cry about compiler not optimizing their code? Some actually do unfortunately...

Comment: @freakish you are in the habit of offering broad generalizations absent any technical explanations. You are not being informative, I prefer to understand my programming principles rather than rely on dogmatic notions. Also, you made an edit just to insinuate that I am "crying" which only further brings your motivation under question.

Comment: @dtech I already explained to you that compiler is not obligated to optimize that. And you've already been told why std::function is different from template, there's no need for me to repeat that. Yet you expect something different for no real reason. It is you who relies on dogmatic notions. Yes, you are crying. I'm done.

Comment: @freakish I suggest you make yourself familiar with the differences between making blanket statements and providing factual argumentation.

Comment: @dtech here are facts: no compiler or C++ standard promised you to optimize this case. Here are facts: you expect something that was never promised, because you believe that compilers will do everything for you. They won't, that's reality, wake up.

Comment: @freakish I thought you were done ;) Not true to your word eh... Your lack of explanations begins to make sense tho, you can't give what you don't have in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem boils down to the fact that `std::function`'s call mechanism is too complex as that it can be reliably inlined.
Among the things necessary for an efficient `std::function` implementation are:

- small object optimization so that smaller function objects don't get stored on the heap
- type erasure, typically using polymorphic classes
- special cases for function pointers to avoid excessive levels of indirection

For the compiler to undo all of these things, it would need to apply

- inlining
- heap elision
- control flow analysis/data flow analysis

... pretty much perfectly. Modern compilers are still quite bad at optimizing anything to do with function pointers.
You're simply expecting too much.

On the other hand, the `template` version is very easily inlined, as seen in the assembly output (https://godbolt.org/z/vvG3fnT5f).
If you can inline `reader`, that enables partial loop unrolling, auto-vectorization, data flow analysis, and other optimizations which improve performance by an order of magnitude.
Inlining makes or breaks it all.

#### Example of Missed Optimizations

Just to illustrate how bad modern compilers are in this field:

```cpp
int fls() { return 0; }
int tru() { return 1; }

int get(int i) {
    static constexpr int(*f[])() = { fls, tru };
    return f[i]();
}
```

Neither Clang nor GCC inline this (https://godbolt.org/z/zqjeG5xff), and both emit something along the lines of:

```
get(int):
        movsx   rdi, edi
        jmp     [QWORD PTR get(int)::f[0+rdi*8]]
```

The theoretical optimum in this very trivial example would be

```cpp
get(int):
        mov eax, edi
        ret
```

This trivial example is asking too much, and inlining all of a `std::function` call dispatch perfectly is asking even more.

Heap elision and function pointer inlining are generally not worth spending much effort on, since you can assume that if a developer is using function pointers and dynamic allocations, they probably need those and you won't be able to just optimize them out.

Comment: I am still unclear on what exactly qualifies the template version to essentially optimize the overhead away unlike the other version, it seems like both versions know the same amount of stuff during the compilation phase. Does the template version pass the lambda as a more easily callable type, and if so, can that be used as a non template parameter instead of std::funciton?

Comment: @dtech as I've said, the inlining makes or breaks it all. In the instantiated `readerT`, there would simply be a static call to `summerT::__lambda`. This can be inlined trivially and then all subsequent optimizations applied. In `reader`, there is a giant wall of branching, small object optimizations, and function pointers standing in the way of any inlining. You end up with a dynamic call to whatever function address `foo` contains each iteration, and no subsequent optimizations at all.

Comment: And yes, in general, the advantage of lambdas and templates is that each lambda has a unique type. Therefore, the compiler never has to inline a function pointer, it knows at compile time that `summerT::__lambda` is called. It can inline it just like any other static call. This is in part why all functions in `<algorithm>` take function objects via template, and not via `std::function` or function pointers.

Comment: Aha, so std::foo always uses dynamic dispatch, even in a 100% static context. That's not really expected from a language that tends to eliminate as much as it can during the compile phase. I'll keep that in mind. The "standard function", not that standard at all :)

Comment: @dtech it's not innate to the language by the way. Both functions could be optimized exactly the same from a theoretical perspective. It's just extremely difficult for compilers to do it in practice, and compiler devs don't focus much on the optimizations that would be necessary to pull it off.

Comment: I wonder if that's the case, does it try and fail, or does it not optimize that particular thing by design.