# Inlining lambda calls to template functions

Tags: c++, templates, optimization, lambda, c++17

I wish to have a template method, which takes in data and processes it with a lambda function, whatever way the method itself wants to do that. However, I want the lambda function to get inlined so that the compiled assembly output won't end up having a "call" assembly instruction. Is this possible?

If it's not possible with lambdas, is there some other way to do that? Somehow using templates to pass a function as a template type or something?

I'm using C++17.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
template <typename T>
static inline void Process(const T*                p_source1,
                           const T*                p_source2,
                           T*                      p_destination,
                           const int               count,
                           std::function<T (T, T)> processor)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        p_destination[i] = processor(p_source1[i], p_source2[i]);
}


void Process_Add(const uint8_t* p_source1,
                 const uint8_t* p_source2,
                 uint8_t*       p_destination,
                 const int      count)
{
    // How to make something like this lambda inline?
    auto lambda = [] (uint8_t a, uint8_t b) { return a + b; };

    Process<uint8_t>(p_source1, p_source2, p_destination, count, lambda);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You have better changes of achieving that if the lambda is passed as a parameter of templated type: `typename U`, `U &&processor`. This plus enabing optimization should do it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm not sure how to do that in practise.

Comment: Just do what I said, add a second template parameter (say, `typename U`), and replace `std::function<T (T, T)> processor` with `U &&processor`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ok, that indeed seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat the code seems to compile to identical assembly code with and without the &&. Why is the && required in that parameter?

Comment: If you pass a capturing lambda, `T` will copy/move it with all the captures (unless you explicitly use `std::ref()`), while `T &&` won't, so `T &&` should usually be better. Notably the standard library uses `T`, for what I guess are historical reasons.

Comment: Side note: `inline` on a function template is practically pretty much always pointless. A template already behaves analogues to `inline` functions even if it isn't `inline`. Similarly `static` is unlikely to be useful. It is only useful if the template is declared in a single source file instead of a header, in which case `static` allows other source files to define the same template differently. On the other hand if that is not the case internal linkage given by `static` may cause the template to not behave as intended. Neither will affect optimization.

Comment: Also, lastly: The combination of `static` and `inline` on a function (or function template) is generally pretty much pointless in C++. If it has internal linkage (`static`) then `inline` serves no purpose, because you can't have two definitions of the entity anyway.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat the C++ standard library uses `T&&` for called-once objects, and `T` for function objects which are called twice or more. You obviously can't `std::move` or `std::forward` something that is used repeatedly, making forwarding references pointless. Rvalue references, lvalue references, and const lvalues references would be too restrictive, so that only leaves `T` as a viable option.

Comment: @JanSchultke You can accept a forwarding reference, and then use it without `forward`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat but why would you do that? It now means you instantiate the function template twice, e.g. for lvalue function pointers and rvalue function pointers. It increases code size, is slower to compile, and you don't even make use of perfect forwarding. It's strictly worse than accepting by value. Even if you have an expensive-to-move invocable type, you can wrap it in a lambda that captures it by reference.

Comment: @JanSchultke *"why would you do that?"* Because it allows you to have pass-by-reference by default (can't forget `std::ref`), while allowing both lvalues and rvalues. The compiler should hopefully remove (effectively) duplicate instantiations. Slower to compile - yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but `std::function` is making it very unlikely because the call mechanism is so complex that it can't be inlined, even in simple cases.
See [Understanding the overhead from std::function and capturing synchronous lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77772452/5740428)

Here's the typical way of making inlining more likely:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename F>
  requires (std::invocable<F, const T&, const T&> // optional: C++20 constraint
        && std::convertible_to<std::invoke_result<F, const T&, const T&>, T>)
inline void Process(const T*  p_source1,
                    const T*  p_source2,
                    T*        p_destination,
                    const int count,
                    F         processor)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        p_destination[i] = processor(p_source1[i], p_source2[i]);
}
```

Each lambda expression has a unique closure type, so `processor(...)` invokes a call operator which is known at compile time.
This makes inlining quite likely, as long as the lambda expression is relatively short.

#### Further notes

You could imitate the C++20 constraint with `std::enable_if_t`, or you could just leave the function unconstrained.

Using `static` and `inline` in combination is basically pointless.
`static` communicates *internal linkage* for functions, and that's likely not your intent, assuming this template is used in more than one cpp file.
See [Should one never use static inline function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10876930/5740428)